# TeamCity Username / password

Tags: passwords, teamcity

Hi 
I installed teamcity longtime ago, on my home computer.
I am trying to re-use it again now, but I forgot the admin username and password
Is there a default admin user name?
and how can I get the password?

Thank

Comment: possible duplicate of [TeamCity forgotten admin password - where to look?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506115/teamcity-forgotten-admin-password-where-to-look)

Comment: @tzot, this is not a duplicate of that question. He is asking for username and password, not only password.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, so you've forgot username and password in your teamcity instance.
**How to reset password**: described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506115/teamcity-forgotten-admin-password-where-to-look).
**How to get username**:

- go to the [teamcity data directory](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/TeamCity+Data+Directory)
- open `config\database.properties` file
- there is `connectionUrl` property which points out to database which stores some teamcity settings
- take a look at `users` table

**Update**

After you get the user name you can reset reset its password via the following(copied from [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506115/teamcity-forgotten-admin-password-where-to-look)):

- Open a command prompt and go to `\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib` folder
- Run the following: `..\..\..\..\jre\bin\java.exe -cp server.jar;common-api.jar;commons-codec-1.3.jar;util.jar;hsqldb.jar ChangePassword username newpassword`

Comment: I know that it's been two years since topic has been started and @gkar's teamcity probably has been re-installed over 9000 times ... I've posted it for future generation, sort of say :)

Comment: These creds are hashed. The answer is not useful.

Comment: @JosephLust, passwords - yes, user names - no, at least as of time of writing the post.

Answer (score 17):

From TeamCity 8 you can log in as a super user and change the password that way. You just need to use an empty username and last occurrence of the "super user authentication token" found in the logs\teamcity-server.log file as your password.

Please see the following for more information:

- TeamCity 8 - http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Super+User
- TeamCity 9 - http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Super+User

Answer (score -1):

FYI, don't follow the advice of going through the `users` table. TeamCity is a quality product, so all passwords are salted/hashed (TC 9 below):

```
mysql [teamcity]> SELECT id,  password FROM users;
+-----+---------------------------------------------------+
|  id | password                                          |
+-----+---------------------------------------------------+
|  21 | k9d9yuE13FtQm8eT:1e24ad492777f94dec0c905127d1ea48 |
|  13 | m1l79Yy03hjoxKdA:199d1ea48e28a78bafde576dd88e6de7 |
|  85 | gOBpYHipOrtEGbUx:88f234847c07085798f9a4f8726e39df |
+-----+---------------------------------------------------+
```